# How to add this request body to my CURL request

Tags: linux, http, curl

I have a post request that I am submitting using CURL:

```
curl -L -X POST https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projectName/subscriptions/subName:pull?key=redactedAPIKey
```

I need to add a request body to the request that looks like this:

```
‘{“returnImmediately”: true, “maxMessages”: 1}’
```

What is the proper syntax for achieving this?

I have tried:

`curl -L -X POST https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projectName/subscriptions/subName:pull?key=redactedAPIKey -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d ‘{“returnImmediately”: true, “maxMessages”: 1}’`

Which failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{'returnImmediately': true, maxMessages: 1}' 'urlHere'
```

Comment: `'{'returnImmediately': true, maxMessages: 1}'` is not valid json, are you sure it worked ?